# How to extract the given list of lines from a file without writing a script

Tags: unix, command-line

The task is this:

For a given list of numbers(potentially very long) like this:

```
1
5
8
...(very long)
```

extract the corresponding line from the second file.

I had to write a simple python code to accomplish this task, but I was wondering if there is a way to do this without resorting to the scripts. Something along the lines of using process substitutions and combination of coreutils:

```
SOME_COMMANDLINE_FU <(cat first_file) second_file
```

The below is the python code I wrote:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import sys
# select.py <LINE_INDEX> <FILE>

line_numbers = open(sys.argv[1],"r").readlines()
line_numbers = map(int, line_numbers)

with open(sys.argv[2],"r") as f:
    index = 1
    for line in f:
        if index in line_numbers:
            print line,
        index = index + 1
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just loop through the numbers file and store them in an array. Then, read the seconf file and check on each line if its number is in the stored array:

```
awk 'FNR==NR {a[$1]; next} FNR in a' file1 file2
```

The `FNR==NR {}` trick makes `{}` to be executed when reading the first file. Then, the rest is executed when reading the second one. More info in [Idiomatic awk](http://backreference.org/2010/02/10/idiomatic-awk/).

Comment: Thank you for sharing the link to Idiomatic awk. Learned some tricks I never thought was possible!

Answer (score 0):

I guess that depends on what is considered a script. One way to extract the lines is to use awk:

```
awk '{system("awk NR=="$1" second_file")}' first_file
```

Comment: The answer by @fedorqui is definitely more elegant (albeit more script-like) with only one call to awk.